# How to change the first SKscene that is presented through gameviewcontroller

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller

[image: error message]

So i have created a couple of different SKScenes in my swift project and I've seen on a couple tutorials that you don't have to launch you gameScene.swift as your first scene, however i can not find a tutorial that explains how

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve 
        rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
  }
}
```

Im trying to change the GameScene SKS to my MainMenu SKS, but i keep getting errors and I'm definitely missing something. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

if let newScene = MenuScene(fileNamed:"MenuScene") {
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve 
    rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    newScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(newScene)
}
}
}
```

So instead of having GameScene as your initial scene, just create MenuScene instance and present it in your `viewDidLoad`. Note that you have to create coresponding MenuScene.sks file because of this line:

`If let newScene = MenuScene(fileNamed:"MenuScene.sks"){
//...}`

because you are loading it from a file.

Also to transition to another scene, use following pattern and for example in touchesBegan create new scene, optionally create SKTransition and present the new scene.

Comment: I tried this method and have created a separate mainMenu.sks file but i still get an error on the "if let line" i uploaded a screenshot it wants me to change filename to coder, but then if i do i get another error that says "cannot convert string value to NS Coder" and i get an error @whirlwind

Comment: According to your uploaded screenshot you will have to delete the code that presents the GameScene and leave ONLY the one that presents the MainMenu scene. Delete the rows:

if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        ...

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just call that code whenever you want. For example, you can connect it with a button.

```
@IBAction func playGame(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I used in a Sprite Kit project. It was I while ago and I dont remember any of the reasoning behind it.

`if let scene = DesiredScene.unarchiveFromFile("DesiredScene") as? DesiredScene`

perhaps someone else can elucidate whats going on